# Comparison of np.arange with C++ iota, iota is slower

Tags: python, c++, numpy, stl

I wrote a small chunk of code to generate a sequence of integers, and compared it with `np.arange()`, and I found `np.arange()` is faster. Anyone can give me some hint if there is any faster C++ implementation of this ?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> range(T start, T end) {
    size_t N = (int)floor(end - start) + 1;
    std::vector<T> vec(N);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), start);
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::vector<int> x_range = range(0, 1024);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

Python code is simple:

```
%timeit x = np.arange(0, 1024)
```

Python time: `1.51e-6 s`
C++ time: `1.6e-5 s`

Python is 10 times faster than C++ implementation here.

Platform:
Win10, Visual Studio Community 2017, in both O2 and Ox optimization mode. Both get more or less the same order of time- `1.x e-5 s`.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing with an optimized build? What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: After including the appropriate headers, mine finished in 0s with `-O2` and `-O3`.

Comment: There is at least one thing the C++ version is doing that the numpy probably isn't: zero-initializing the buffer before filling it.

Comment: I use visual studio 2017 community version, in release mode x64, in both O2 and Ox optimization, I tried both, both are about 1.x e-5 s.

Comment: Seriously? 1.5 microseconds and 16 microseconds? Measurements of such small individual workloads are never reliable.

Comment: Call your 'range` function 1 000 000 times in a loop.

Comment: I just tried generating a sequence up to 1000000, C++ implementation remained to microseconds, however, python increase dramatically to milliseconds.

Comment: @ted930511: I would increase the number of repetitions until the longer of the two times is at least one second. Alternatively, you can increase the size of the range by a large number (as much as your RAM size will allow).

Comment: Yes, agreed, I am testing on that NOW!!!

Comment: @Violet Giraffe, thank you for your advice!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everybody, although it is a simple piece of question, but I still learns a lot.

Here is new code which is different from code in the question, maybe the compassion will help some newbies understand better:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> range(T start, T end) {
    size_t N = (int)floor(end - start);
    std::vector<T> vec;
    vec.reserve(N);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), start);
    return vec;
}

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        std::vector<int> x_range = range(0, 1000);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
    system("pause");

}
```

Now C++ implementation time: 7.14136e-8 s.

Comment: This code is wrong: reserve does not change vec.end(), so your std::iota is not doing anything.